# How can I add a way to jump months using the calendar module

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a calendar being shown by month. How can I add an exposed filter or dropdown so users can jump ahead to any month and year?

Comment: Each month display has a predictable URL, eg: May 2016 might be domain.org/16/05/. Can you use a menu to just take them to the relevant URL?

Comment: What have you already tried? Views, Date, and BEF provide some of this ability out of the box (one solution here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2481343).

Answer (score 1):

Add Below code for your calendar. [Click This link for example](https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/VBGKU/)

```
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
 });
});
```